# Grails 3.3.x angular profile domain creation

Tags: grails

I am following this tutorial using grails 3.3.x 
https://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-angularjs-springsecurity-workshop/

after creating the app

```
$grails create-app --profile angular -features hibernate5,json-views todo
```

I try to create an angular domain

```
~/todo/server/$ grails create-ng-domain todo
```

but I get

```
| Error Command not found create-ng-domain
```

while create-ng-domain todo works for the rest-api profile

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`create-ng-domain` is now part of the `angularjs` profile, not the `angular` profile.

See https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10850.

Comment: The article you link there was written for Grails 3.2.6 and you are using Grails 3.3.x.  3.2.8 was the last version of Grails for which what you originally tried would have worked.